# Terraform use Variable from random function

Tags: terraform

I´m a beginner in Terraform.
I like to know, how can I use a variable which was generated in a random function in the same .tr script and use it like below for a different input. I´m also not sure, if the random stuff is working correctly? Can someone help me? But how to pass the varibale?

for example

```
locals {
  dslist = [
    "Datastore1",
    "Datastore2",
    "Datastore3"
  ]
}

resource "random_shuffle" "random_dslist" {
  input = local.dslist
  result_count = 1
}

output "random_dslist" {
  value = random_shuffle.random_dslist.result
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = "${var.random_dslist}"  # -> how can I pass the generated random datastore in here?
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value of the resource just like you already used it for the output:

Only difference here is that, according to the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/shuffle) `random_shuffle.result` gives you a list, since you can get more than one random result. Therefore, just take the first result `[0]`, because you know that you expect only one item in the list.

```
resource "random_shuffle" "random_dslist" {
  input = local.dslist
  result_count = 1
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name = random_shuffle.random_dslist.result[0]
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks..
how can I check the output of the var 'random_dslist'  a quick check if the random_shuffle works correct? 

do I need acctually the result_count = 1?

Comment: You should see the output when you execute terraform plan. But also, I think it's not your responsibility to check if this resource works since it's provided by hashicorp and should work properly. 

And yes you need result_count. Take a look at the documentation :D